# “$ x $ is a brother of $ y $.” Why is this not transitive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I am working on a problem set at the moment, and while checking my answers I realized that I have listed "x is a brother of y" as a transitive relation, while the answers say that it is not.

**EDIT**: I realized I forgot to put some assumptions from the question: 
i) Domain is people in general.
ii) Assume that all siblings **share both parents.**

But if x is a brother of y, and y is a brother of z, then surely x is a brother of z? Am I missing something here?

Please help a student out. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose $x$ and $y$ only share a mother, and $y$ and $z$ only share a father.

Comment: People don't often think that they are their own brothers.

Comment: @Polichinelle I think you nailed it.

Comment: @Polichinelle Why not make that an answer?

Comment: The problem with this question is that it is not about math, but about the interpretation of the word "brother ". If you replace "brother" with "share both parents" then the relation becomes reflexive and transitive.

Comment: @Polichinelle: The OP is missing the assumption that nobody is schizophrenic.

Comment: @Berrick Schizophrenia does not mean multiple personalities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If Fred is Bob's brother, and vice versa, transitivity would imply that Fred is his own brother.

Comment: And why is being your own brother a contradiction? *Note:* I would define a brother of Fred as a son of his parents.

Comment: @A.P.: And I could equally define each person to be that same person's *only* brother -- but if I did that, you would probably object that that is not how the word is used by people in the real world.  Do you see how that same objection applies to your definition?

Comment: @A.P. - I'm an only child. How many brothers do I have? None. Yes, if you squint just right, you can pretend that the right answer is one, but you'll have a hard time getting anyone else to agree.

Comment: @PeteBecker so in your case its transitive right? cause the definition is if (a,b) and (b,c) exists we need (a,c) for transitivity... there's no (a,b) or (b,c) here...

Answer (score 1):

Transitivity says:

$aRb$ and $bRc$ imply $aRc$

$x$ is a brother of $y$, $y$ is a brother of $x$, but $x$ is not a brother of $x$.

Therefore, it's not a transitive relation.

Answer (score 1):

If X is the brother of Y and Y is the brother of X, then X is his own brother, if it were transitive.

Answer (score -1):

What if Y is female.  So X is a brother of Y, but Y is a sister of X.

Comment: This means that the "brotherhood" relation isn't symmetric, not that it isn't transitive.